# Add a transition to the submenu

Tags: jquery, html, css

Help me to add a transition to the submenu. Although I have tried using transition but it didn't work. I want the transition to happen when the mouse hovers over.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Here's the code:

CSS part:

```css
.neighborhood-guides {
 top: -20px;
 position: relative;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

.neighborhood-guides h2 {
    color: #393c3d;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.neighborhood-guides p {
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
/*.nav {
 height: 160px;

}

.nav  img{
 position: absolute;
 height: 150px;
 display: block;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -50px;
}*/

.nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li:hover {
 background: gray;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

a.dropdown-toggle:hover + ul.dropdown-menu, ul.dropdown-menu:hover {
display: block;
} 

.dropdown-menu { margin-top: 0; } 

.carousel {
 display: cover;
}

.carousel-inner {
 top: -20px;
 
}

.learn-more {
 top: -20px;
 position: relative;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

.learn-more h3 {
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.learn-more a {
  color: #00b0ff;
}

footer , .row {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

footer img:hover {
 background: orange;
 cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) {
 .carousel-caption {
 top: 20%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 position: absolute;
 text-align: left;
}
 .carousel-caption h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel-caption a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: orange;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 310px) {
 .carousel-caption {
 top: 30%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 position: absolute;
 text-align: left;
}
 .carousel-caption h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel-caption a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: orange;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .carousel-caption {
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 position: absolute;
 text-align: left;
}
 .carousel-caption h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel-caption a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: orange;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>     
  <head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">    
    
  </head>

  <body>
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
 <div class="container">
  <a href = "#" class="navbar-brand">Easy Trip</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">all<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">America</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
        </ul>
   
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
  
  </div>
      </div>
 </div>
    
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
     <img src="http://hdwall.us/wallpaper_1920x1080/sun_cherry_blossoms_trees_flowers_desktop_1920x1080_hd-wallpaper-1194807.jpg" class="img-responsive">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h1>Find a place to stay.</h1>
     <p>Rent from people in over 34,000 cities and 192 countries.</p>
     <a href="#">Learn More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <img src="http://xinature.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/forests-view-trees-sunlight-landscape-nature-sun-tree-sunrasy-sunrise-splendor-lovely-sunset-beautiful-woods-forest-magic-peaceful-rays-beauty-sky-hd-backgrounds-1920x1080.jpg" class="img-responsive">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h1>Find a place to stay.</h1>
     <p>Rent from people in over 34,000 cities and 192 countries.</p>
     <a href="#">Learn More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/belgium_winter_garden_sun_sky_clearly_trees_60892_1920x1080.jpg" class="img-responsive">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h1>Find a place to stay.</h1>
     <p>Rent from people in over 34,000 cities and 192 countries.</p>
     <a href="#">Learn More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
     <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
     </a>
     <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next"></span>
     </a>
   </div>
  </div>    
    
    <div class="neighborhood-guides">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Neighborhood Guides</h2>
            <p>Not sure where to stay? We've created neighborhood guides for cities all around the world.</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/World-Beautiful-places-Paris-HD-Wallpapers.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/World-Beautiful-places-Desktop-HD-Wallpapers.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://www.wallpapers-web.com/data/out/28/3948828-beautiful-places-wallpapers.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/50/d5/22/50d52265980da137e18d3f85a5d9290e.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://swiss7.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Top-20-safest-countries-in-the-world-for-solo-travelers.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://www.hd-wallpaper1.com/images/abandoned-place.jpeg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="learn-more">
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3>Travel</h3>
   <p>From apartments and rooms to treehouses and boats: stay in unique spaces in 192 countries.</p>
   <p><a href="#">See how to travel on Airbnb</a></p>
       </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3>Host</h3>
   <p>Renting out your unused space could pay your bills or fund your next vacation.</p>
   <p><a href="#">Learn more about hosting</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3>Trust and Safety</h3>
   <p>From Verified ID to our worldwide customer support team, we've got your back.</p>
   <p><a href="#">Learn about trust at Airbnb</a></p>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <footer class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <p class="pull-left">
        &copy; 2017 Shoppiz
      </p>
      <ul class="col-sm-8 pull-right" style="list-style: none; display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/twitter.svg" style="height:28px; width:28px"></li>
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/facebook.svg" style="height:28px; width:28px"></li>
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/instagram.svg" style="height:28px; width:28px"></li>
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/medium.svg" style="height:28px; width:28px"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </footer>
 
  </body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>$("#myCarousel").carousel({interval:5000});</script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what you need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.neighborhood-guides {
 top: -20px;
 position: relative;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

.neighborhood-guides h2 {
    color: #393c3d;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.neighborhood-guides p {
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li:hover {
 background: gray;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

a.dropdown-toggle:hover + ul.dropdown-menu,
ul.dropdown-menu:hover {
  opacity: 1;
} 

.dropdown-menu { 
  display: block !important;
  margin-top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
} 

.dropdown-menu,
.dropdown-menu li,
.dropdown-menu li a {
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.learn-more {
 top: -20px;
 position: relative;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}
```

```html
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
  

 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
 <div class="container">
  <a href = "#" class="navbar-brand">Easy Trip</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">all<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">America</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
        </ul>
   
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
  
  </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>$("#myCarousel").carousel({interval:5000});</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `transition` property: `transition: all .3s ease;`. Where `.3s` is the duration in seconds.

Set the `.dropdown-menu` to `display: block`. Than hide it with `visibility: hidden`. Using only `opacity: 0;` it will be still visible, be it with an transparent color.

I edited the following lines for you to get the desired result:

```
ul.dropdown-menu,
a.dropdown-toggle:hover + ul.dropdown-menu, ul.dropdown-menu:hover {
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}

a.dropdown-toggle:hover + ul.dropdown-menu, ul.dropdown-menu:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```css
.neighborhood-guides {
 top: -20px;
 position: relative;
    background-color: #efefef;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

.neighborhood-guides h2 {
    color: #393c3d;
    font-size: 24px;
}

.neighborhood-guides p {
    margin-bottom: 13px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

.thumbnail:hover {
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}



/*.nav {
 height: 160px;

}

.nav  img{
 position: absolute;
 height: 150px;
 display: block;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -50px;
}*/


.nav a {
 text-decoration: none;
  color: #5a5a5a;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav li:hover {
 background: gray;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

a.dropdown-toggle:hover + ul.dropdown-menu, ul.dropdown-menu:hover {
  display: block;
  
  animation-name: fade-in;
    animation-duration: .4s;
} 

.dropdown-menu { margin-top: 0; } 

.carousel {
 display: cover;
}

.carousel-inner {
 top: -20px;
 
}

.learn-more {
 top: -20px;
 position: relative;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
}

.learn-more h3 {
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.learn-more a {
  color: #00b0ff;
}

footer , .row {
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

footer img:hover {
 background: orange;
 cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) {
 .carousel-caption {
 top: 20%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 position: absolute;
 text-align: left;
}
 .carousel-caption h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel-caption a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: orange;
}
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 310px) {
 .carousel-caption {
 top: 30%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 position: absolute;
 text-align: left;
}
 .carousel-caption h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel-caption a {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: orange;
}
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
 .carousel-caption {
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
 position: absolute;
 text-align: left;
}
 .carousel-caption h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 48px;  
  font-family: 'Shift', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.carousel-caption p {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.carousel-caption a {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: orange;
}
}

@keyframes fade-in {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
  <head>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/shift.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 
    
  </head>

  <body>
 <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
 <div class="container">
  <a href = "#" class="navbar-brand">Easy Trip</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">all<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
   <li><a href="#">Asia</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Africa</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Europe</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">America</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
        </ul>
   
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
  
  </div>
      </div>
 </div>
    
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
   </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
     <img src="http://hdwall.us/wallpaper_1920x1080/sun_cherry_blossoms_trees_flowers_desktop_1920x1080_hd-wallpaper-1194807.jpg" class="img-responsive">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h1>Find a place to stay.</h1>
     <p>Rent from people in over 34,000 cities and 192 countries.</p>
     <a href="#">Learn More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <img src="http://xinature.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/forests-view-trees-sunlight-landscape-nature-sun-tree-sunrasy-sunrise-splendor-lovely-sunset-beautiful-woods-forest-magic-peaceful-rays-beauty-sky-hd-backgrounds-1920x1080.jpg" class="img-responsive">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h1>Find a place to stay.</h1>
     <p>Rent from people in over 34,000 cities and 192 countries.</p>
     <a href="#">Learn More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
     <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/belgium_winter_garden_sun_sky_clearly_trees_60892_1920x1080.jpg" class="img-responsive">
     <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h1>Find a place to stay.</h1>
     <p>Rent from people in over 34,000 cities and 192 countries.</p>
     <a href="#">Learn More</a>
     </div>
    </div>
     <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
     </a>
     <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next"></span>
     </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 
    
    <div class="neighborhood-guides">
        <div class="container">
            <h2>Neighborhood Guides</h2>
            <p>Not sure where to stay? We've created neighborhood guides for cities all around the world.</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/World-Beautiful-places-Paris-HD-Wallpapers.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://hdwallpaperbackgrounds.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/World-Beautiful-places-Desktop-HD-Wallpapers.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://www.wallpapers-web.com/data/out/28/3948828-beautiful-places-wallpapers.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/50/d5/22/50d52265980da137e18d3f85a5d9290e.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://swiss7.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Top-20-safest-countries-in-the-world-for-solo-travelers.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <img src="http://www.hd-wallpaper1.com/images/abandoned-place.jpeg">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="learn-more">
   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3>Travel</h3>
   <p>From apartments and rooms to treehouses and boats: stay in unique spaces in 192 countries.</p>
   <p><a href="#">See how to travel on Airbnb</a></p>
       </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3>Host</h3>
   <p>Renting out your unused space could pay your bills or fund your next vacation.</p>
   <p><a href="#">Learn more about hosting</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
   <h3>Trust and Safety</h3>
   <p>From Verified ID to our worldwide customer support team, we've got your back.</p>
   <p><a href="#">Learn about trust at Airbnb</a></p>
    </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <footer class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <p class="pull-left">
        &copy; 2017 Shoppiz
      </p>
      <ul class="col-sm-8 pull-right" style="list-style: none; display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/twitter.svg" style="height:28px; width:28px"></li>
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/facebook.svg" style="height:28px; width:28px"></li>
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/instagram.svg" style="height:28px; width:28px"></li>
        <li class="col-sm-1"><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/make-a-website/lesson-4/medium.svg" style="height:28px; width:28px"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </footer>
 
  </body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>$("#myCarousel").carousel({interval:5000});</script>
</html>
```

An shorter solution to the above solution would be to use `@keyframes`

Add the following `CSS` to your `CSS` file:

```
@keyframes fade-in {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Than call it indside the `.dropdown-menu` class like this:

```
a.dropdown-toggle:hover + ul.dropdown-menu, ul.dropdown-menu:hover {
    display: block;
    animation-name: fade-in;
    animation-duration: .3s;
}
```